# how to highlight selected item with color in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is My Folders UI and when I click or select any one folder i want to highlight that specific folder with green color and second question is i hover mouse on any other folder I want to highlight that folder with yellow color. each folder has its different folderid

[image]

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs (dblclick)="addNewFolderRoute(folder.folderid)">
  <mat-icon>folder</mat-icon>
  <span>{{folder.folderName}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: For hover, I would suggest to use CSS `:hover` selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let folder of folderObjs" (dblclick)="addNewFolderRoute(folder.folderid)" (click)="activeFolder=folder" class="folder" [class.green]="folder==activeFolder">
    <mat-icon>folder</mat-icon>
    <span>{{folder.folderName}}</span>
</div>
```

and css

```
.folder:hover {
   background:yellow;
 }

.folder.green {
   background:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt to helping for me hover functionality works, but on one click it not shows green with selected

Comment: try this : `[ngClass]="'green':activeFolder"`

Comment: @Matt it works perfectly thank you but what is folder==activeFolder ?

Comment: it toggles on the .green class when the current `folder` in the loop is equal to the variable '`activeFolder`